# Typescript return value type

Tags: typescript

Just curious why am i getting such an error:

> Type  '(Float64Array | [number, Friends][])[]' is not assignable to
>   type '[[number, Friends][], Float64Array]'.    Property '0' is missing
>   in type '(Float64Array | [number, Friends][])[]'.

Related code:

```
 export let process_data = ([connections,target]) : [[user_id, Friends][], Matrix_float64] =>   
         compose(         
            (list : [user_id, Friends][]) => 
                 [list,construct_matrix(list)]; 
            , .....  

let construct_matrix = (list : [user_id, Friends][]) :  Matrix_float64 => {
...
```

I can force it with typecast, but is this correct behavior? I'm using last version of typescript.

Edit: 
Here is types:

```
export interface Friends {
    count:number,   
    overall:number,
    items:number[]  
};         

export type user_id = number;
```

Here is example of data contained in variable `list`:

```
[ [ 136444868, { count: 304, overall: 304, items: [Object] } ],
  [ 5686439, { count: 4, overall: 510, items: [Object] } ],
  [ 5501650, { count: 8, overall: 360, items: [Object] } ],
  [ 5440602, { count: 5, overall: 344, items: [Object] } ],
  [ 5366101, { count: 0, overall: 29, items: [] } ],....
```

When i'm doing this `return  [list,construct_matrix(list)] as [[user_id, Friends][],Matrix_float64];` (repeat same return type as in function definition) error is gone, everything is fine. So compiler not looking on my definition?

Comment: That error message does not seem to relate to the code, or it's not complete enough for us to understand that. Can you provide the prototype of `compose` and explain what it does? Also note that a type `[A, B]` is very different from `A | B`.

Comment: compose is standard function for composition of the functions, im using implementation from ramda library, i never got such error before, i will augment question with more details

Comment: Can you expose the call to `compose` further? Also, what happens if you remove the semi-colon after `[list,construct_matrix(list)]`?

Comment: There's open issue for that https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13883

Comment: oh i see thank you artem